# mixins overwriting media queried style

Tags: css, sass

I have some JS functionality that changes the css class on my body element. Based on a click, i will change the css class of my body element to one of the following: `.font-default`, `.font-medium`, and `.font-large`.

I have the following mixins that determines the font size of an element based on the `body` element's class. That looks like this:

```
@function rem-calc($size) {
  $remSize: $size / 16;
  @return #{$remSize}rem;
}

@mixin font-size($size) {
  @if $size >= 20 {
    font-size: rem-calc($size);
  } @else if $size == 18 {
    font-size: rem-calc(18);

    .font-large & {
      font-size: rem-calc(20);
    }
  } @else {
    font-size: rem-calc($size);

    .font-medium & {
      font-size: rem-calc($size + 2);
    }

    .font-large & {
      font-size: rem-calc($size + 4);
    }
  }
}
```

An example of me using this mixin is as follows:

```
.content {
  @include font-size(16);

  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
    @include font-size(30);
  }
}
```

Here's is the corresponding html and css on the linked codepen at the bottom:

```
<body class="body">
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <button class="button">
    click to add
  </button>  
</body>

<script>
const button = document.querySelector('.button')
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.body')) 
  document.querySelector('.body').classList.add('font-medium');
})
</script>
```

According to my ruleset (the mixin), in the desktop version, `font-size` should remain unchanged since `size >= 20`. However in practice, when I click the button that changes the class to medium, it uses the "mobile" version of the style and overwrites the style that's placed in the media query.

Is there anyway regarding specificity such that I can still use this mixin so that the mobile styles don't bleed into the styles nested in the media queries?

If not, what might be a different solution to this problem?

Here's a pen that shows the issue. When clicking the button, I want the font to remain unchanged. https://codepen.io/rv-akim/pen/WVJpWj

Comment: Can you add the actual generated css so we can clearly see which rule is overwriting which other rule?

Comment: Yeah, i can try to make a pen

Comment: If you just add the css, it will be fairly easy to see what's happening. You can even do this using inspector, just copy the rule that is in effect and the rule that is being overridden, you won't even need a pen

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: On your page, inspect the element that is not working for you and see why the font size isn't what you are expecting

Comment: ah yeah, i see what you mean, yes, so initially, before i click the "medium text" i see that font size is derived from the media query, then. I clicked the "medium text" button and the mixin overwrites the mediaquerys font size

Comment: Yes I get that part but you need to post the generated css, your posted SASS code generates css and there is some issue with it, so post the generated css specifically what's overwriting what, post the offending css rules. From what you have there it is hard to tell what's actually happening on the page because we don't know the actual css rules that is generated

Comment: i added a pen, i hope it helps, it's doing the same behaviors. I'm sorry huang, i can visually see the generated css, but i'm not sure that would be as helpful as the pen.

Comment: You can clearly see that `.font-medium .content` is overriding `.content` due to the fact the former is more specific. Just add a normal state class so this does not occur

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with what a state class, is taht a class i can just add to the mixin?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything special, don't read too much into it. Add class `normal` for example to body, then update your mixin to use the normal class to target the font size when font-medium and font-large is NOT in use

Comment: so in more or less words, i need to increase specificity on my media queries?

Comment: Yes, if you use Inspector you see this right away, if you don't know what inspector is, right click and click on inspect, this tool is available in most browsers

Comment: Sure, i'll give it a shot, thanks a lot, if you want to submit an answer with updates to code, I can credit ya if you care, Either way, this gives me enough to solution this I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clearly see that `.font-medium .content` is overriding `.content` due to the fact the former is more specific even though `.content` is inside of a media query.

Update your code so your normal state of the font size uses a class

```
@mixin font-size($size) {
  @if $size >= 20 {
    .normal & {
      font-size: rem-calc($size);
    }
  } @else if $size == 18 {
    .normal & {
      font-size: rem-calc(18);
    }
    .font-large & {
      font-size: rem-calc(20);
    }
  } @else {
    .normal & {
      font-size: rem-calc($size);
    }

    .font-medium & {
      font-size: rem-calc($size + 2);
    }

    .font-large & {
      font-size: rem-calc($size + 4);
    }
  }
}

.content {
  @include font-size(16);

  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
    @include font-size(30);
  }
}
```

Add class normal to your body tag

```
<body class="body normal">
```

Basically, where you only declared the font size rule, I wrapped it with  `.normal & {}`

If you learn to use the Inspector, it will save you tons of headaches later